# Google Oauth2.0:

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, dialogflow-es, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm using the Google NodeJS client sample with DialogFlow fulfilment server: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/tree/master/samples.

Generated my Google API Web Client credential, with my redirect url to https://xxxxxx.ngrok.io

Then downloaded JSON and renamed to oauth2.keys.json in samples folder.

```
{
    "web": {
        "client_id": "XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "project_id": "XXXX",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_secret": "XXXX",
        "redirect_uris": ["https://XXXX.ngrok.io"]
    }
}
```

When I run node oauth2.js, I'm directed to a website and am prompted to login to a google account. I have the following error :

> keys.redirect_uris[0] , TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

The DialogFlow fulfilment server is also running at the ngrok address.

UPDATE 24 may:

after logging into google account:

```
Headers {
  "host": "xxxx.ngrok.io",
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/xx.x.xxxx.xxx Safari/537.36",
  "accept": "image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8",
  "referer": "https://xxxxxxx.ngrok.io/?code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
  "accept-language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
  "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
  "x-forwarded-for": "xxx.xx.xx.xxx"
}

TypeError: Cannot read property 'payload' of undefined
    at getRequest (/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/facts/functions/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/conv.js:30:45)
    at new DialogflowConversation (/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/facts/functions/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/conv.js:37:22)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/facts/functions/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:113:24)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/xxxxxxx/Desktop/facts/functions/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:22:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/facts/functions/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:18:12)
    at Function.handler (/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/facts/functions/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:84:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/facts/functions/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/assistant.js:55:32)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're actually trying to *run* oauth2.js, make sure the `oauth2.keys.json` file is in the same directory as the oauth2.js file. If you're just using oauth2.js as an example for generating your own tokens, you can modify the file to read the keys from any location that makes sense for you.

Comment: yes, there are in the same directory. Precisely because of that, i'm not too sure why the error occurs. Was thinking if the redirect uri (url) is wrong?